# Unable to update stepper active icon color for material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react material ui and having issues changing the color for the following highlight class.

[image]

CSS

```
  stepIcon: {
    '&$active': {
      color: '#1e88e5',
    },
  },
```

```
                  <StepLabel
                    classes={{
                      root: classes.stepIcon,
                    }}
                  >
                    {label}

                  </StepLabel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the `classes`(especially the `active`) properties are not working for `StepLabel`. I tried and went with a different approach.
You can override the styles by changing the global theme or you can use styled-components.

Below is a sample example of how I override the styles.

[image: Edit HorizontalLinearAlternativeLabelStepper Material Demo (forked)]